# Convert a time to a specific timezone in moment timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, react-native, timezone, momentjs

I have a date `2018-06-19 09:06:29`. It is how it is stored in the database. I am using `moment-timezone` and calling this function.

```
function getDateString(t, tz) {
    return moment()
    .tz("America/Chicago")
    .format('l');
}
```

Here I know that my `timezone` is "America/Chicago" and it is "UTC-5 hours". I should get the time 5 hours before the time that I have passed as an argument.

This function was working perfectly until I upgraded my react. Can anyone know what might be the issue?

**These are my current settings of react**

```
"expo": "^27.0.0",
"moment": "^2.22.2",
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-moment": "^0.7.0",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.17",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-27.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-swipeable": "^0.6.0",
"react-navigation": "1.5.11"
```

Comment: "This function was working perfectly" it seems to me that this function is not doing anything with what I guess is your date/time argument `t`

Comment: also, please give exact output you get, and the one you used to get, there are often some confusions about what a date time *is* as data, and how it is *represented* as string / message, with all the fancy timezone and locale stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comments, not sure exactly what is going wrong (and how it used to work on your side), but here is how it should work to me :

1. Create a moment with your date time, specifying that this is expressed as utc, with `moment.utc()`
2. convert it to your timezone with `moment.tz()`

This would give something like :

```
function getDateString(t, tz) {
    return moment.utc(t, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
    .tz("America/Chicago")
    .format('l');
}
```